# unordered_map of std::ofstream

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unordered-map

I'd like to use a `std::unordered_map<unsigned,std::ofstream>` but failed. Now I wonder whether this is simply impossible, or a compiler issue, or whether I just didn't get it right. The problem is the insertion of another element:

```
std::ofstream&get(unsigned key, std::unordered_map<unsigned,std::ofstream>&map)
{
  auto file = map.find(key);
  if(file==map.end()) {
    map.emplace(std::make_pair(key,std::ofstream{}));  // <-- trouble here
    file = map.find(key);
    assert(file!=map.end());
  }
  return file->second;
}
```

fails with gcc (4.8.1), because `std::ofstream` is not copy-constructible.

However, it is move-constructible, so there ought to be a solution, or not? (all I want to insert is a default-constructed `std::ofstream`). I tried to add
some `std::move()`s, but that didn't help.

I just noted that the above code does compile with clang 3.4. Isn't this wrong?

Comment: It's most likely a problem with GCC and/or its standard library. Clang and it's libc++ standard library have always had much more mature C++11 compliance than GCC/libstdc++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you make a pair first then ask map to construct the pair again and cause the problem

try

```
map.emplace(key,std::ofstream{});
```

---

actually, all you need is

```
std::ofstream&get(unsigned key, std::unordered_map<unsigned,std::ofstream>&map)
{
  return map[key];
}
```

or remove this function... and use `map[key]`

because map will construct `ofstream` using default constructor if a non-exist key was used, so it should works like your code

Comment: same problem (with gcc 4.8.1, fine with clang 3.4), also `std::move(std::ofstream{})` doesn't help. Perhaps this is an issue with gcc's c++ library?

Comment: @Walter actually you don't need this function at all.

Comment: excellent! I suppose, this is not threadsafe ... so I need a mutex (and then I still need this function)

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to GCC compiler either will all others presumably, basic_fstream offers fairly simple operations, on top of this file stream does not have copy operations. 
The solution is if you want two names to refer to the same file stream, use a reference or a pointer or manipulate file streambufs.

STL uses copy often, the above with `emplace` or `make_pair`  uses copy
little more convenient notation for `insert()`. The
result of `m[k]` is equivalent to the result of `(*(<map>.insert(make_pair(k,V{})).first)).second`, where `V` is the mapped
type, so there is no move in there.

Subtle difference to move and copy is that after a copy two objects
must have the same value, whereas after a move the source of the
move is not required to have its original value. Moves can be used
when the source object will not be used again. They are particularly
useful for implementing the notion of moving a resource.For the most interesting cases, containers, that moved-from state is “empty.”

There are five situations in which an object is copied or moved:
• As the source of an assignment
• As an object initialiser
• As a function argument
• As a function return value
• As an exception
In all cases, the copy or move constructor will be applied (unless it
can be optimized away).

Reckon there is bleak chance to accommodate this in the current standard, that not over
aforementioned in your case, could you not use a pointer to the ofstream?, like

```
unordered_map<int, ofstream*> map1;
map1.emplace(1, new ofstream());
```

Do you have any idea on other compilers which work with move?

Comment: no no no. `map.insert(make_pair(k,V{}))` doesn't compile with gcc's c++ library, but `map[k]` does. So they are not equivalent. Perhaps they should be, though. `map<int, ofstream*>` is *exactly* what I wanted to avoid. (btw, if you really want/must use pointers, than not via raw pointers, but `map<int, unique_ptr<ofstream>>`)